# Is it possibile to create dashed border controlling the length and the spacing?

Tags: css

Is it possibile to control the length and the distance between the strokes?
I would like to create this effect without svg.
Is it possibile?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot customize these things with CSS. They are hardcoded into each browser implementation, and different browsers draw dashed borders in different ways.

If you'd rather not use SVG, your only other alternative is background images (SVG itself is an image format, anyway).